# Nesting three components in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, components

I was trying to pass a function deleteComment() from my parent component to the child component so that when the child component is clicked, it will run deleteComment(). As you can see, I defined deleteComment() in CommentBox and passed it down to the CommentList component and then the Comment component. When I tried pass it down only once to CommentList, the onClick event work and deleteComment ran, but once I pass it down another level, it does not. Am I referring to the function incorrectly while nesting multiple components?

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  rawMarkup: function() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="comment" onClick={this.props.onDeleteComment}>
        <h3 className="commentTag"><span className="commentTitle">{this.props.title}</span> by <span className="commentAuthor">{this.props.author}</span><i className="fa fa-times"></i></h3>
        <div className="commentBody"><span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()}/></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
     return (
       <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id} title={comment.title}>
         {comment.text}
       </Comment>
     );
   });
   return(
     <div className="commentList" onDeleteComment={this.props.onDelete}>
        {commentNodes}
     </div>
   )
  }
});

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
     var comments = this.state.data;
     comment.id = Date.now();
     var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
     this.setState({data: newComments});
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: comments});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  deleteComment: function() {
    alert("test");
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
   this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
 },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="commentBox">
        <ul className="mainBar">
          <li className="active">Updates</li>
        </ul>
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit}/>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} onDelete={this.deleteComment}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox url="/api/comments" pollInterval={500} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CommentList` is rendering

```
return( 
  <div className="commentList" onDeleteComment={this.props.onDelete}>
    {commentNodes}
  </div>
)
```

You want to pass `onDeleteComment` to your `Comment`s, not the div wrapping them.

But since it's being `.map`d with an anonymous function, scoping changes. Tell it what `this` should be with `.bind`

```
  this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
   return (
     <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id} title={comment.title} onDeleteComment={this.props.onDelete}>
       {comment.text}
     </Comment>
   );
  }.bind(this))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried applying it directly to my Comments within that div but I get an error that props is undefined.

Comment: Oh, you had `<Comment onDeleteComment={this.props.onDelete} ...`?

Since that `.map` is calling a callback like that, the scoping is different. Answer edited.